# How can I implement lambda-mart with lightgbm?

Tags: machine-learning, python, information-retrieval, lightgbm, learning-to-rank

I have a learning to rank task at hand and I want to use the [lightgbm implementation of LambdaMART](https://lightgbm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pythonapi/lightgbm.LGBMRanker.html#). I'm also following this [notebook](https://everdark.github.io/k9/notebooks/ml/learning_to_rank/learning_to_rank.html).

```
param = {
"task": "train",
"num_leaves": 255,
"min_data_in_leaf": 1,
"min_sum_hessian_in_leaf": 100,
"objective": "lambdarank",
"metric": "ndcg",
"ndcg_eval_at": [1, 3, 5, 10],
"learning_rate": .1,
"num_threads": 2}

res = {}
bst = lgb.train(
    param, train_data, 
    valid_sets=[valid_data], valid_names=["valid"],
    num_boost_round=50, evals_result=res, verbose_eval=10)
```

In the params, the objective is set to `lambda-rank` which is another learning to rank algorithm. My question is, how do I implement `LambdaMART` with `lightgbm` ? What set of paramters should I use to implement `LambdaMART` with `lightgbm` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the implementation of lambdaMART in the notebook referenced in the question is correct.

From the paper titled, [From RankNet to LambdaRank to LambdaMART: An Overview](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/MSR-TR-2010-82.pdf), it is clearly mentioned in the first line of the paper that :

> LambdaMART is the boosted tree version of LambdaRank, which is based on
> RankNet.

So, the code that's pasted above clearly says that, the objective function is LambdaRank. There is one more arguement called `boosting_type` which is set to `gbdt` by default. The `LambdaRank + gbdt` is what `LambdaMART` is in essence.

So, just pasting the above code for completion sake:

```
param = { "task": "train", 
          "num_leaves": 255,
          "min_data_in_leaf": 1,
          "min_sum_hessian_in_leaf": 100,
          "objective": "lambdarank",
          "boosting_type": "gbdt",
          "metric": "ndcg",
          "ndcg_eval_at": [1, 3, 5, 10],
          "learning_rate": .1,
          "num_threads": 2 }

res = {}
bst = lgb.train(
param, train_data, 
valid_sets=[valid_data], valid_names=["valid"],
num_boost_round=50, evals_result=res, verbose_eval=10)
```

This is how we can use lightgbm to train lambdaMART.